# TYPO3 Extbase getArguments from other Extension

Tags: typo3, extbase

I've got an extension with two plugins and I need to access the getVars from both.

```
$this->request->getArguments();
```

The above code gives me, of course, only the vars from the current plugin.

Anybody knows how I can access the Vars from a different plugin?

Thank's alot!

Cheers,

lufi

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inside an extension, you do not have access to the request arguments of an other extension. This is only possible using the old way via

`$_REQUEST` or `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GP("varname");`

Check out:
`\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\DebugUtility::debug($_REQUEST);` to get the right array keys and var names.