# TYPO3 Access parameter from other extension

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-10.x

In TYPO3, I have two plugins on the same page, lets call them pluginA and pluginB.
The page gets called with parameters for pluginA like this:

```
tx_pluginA[action]=show&tx_pluginA[controller]=MyController&tx_pluginA[object]=1
```

Now in the show action of MyController I get the object directly as parameter in the show action.

But is there an easy way I can access this object from pluginB without having to manually parse the GET parameters and retrieving the object from the database?

Of course I could inject the repository and do something like:

```
$pluginsParams = GeneralUtility::_GET('tx_pluginB_model');
$title = $this->pluginBRepository->findByUid($pluginsParams['model'])->getTitle();
```

I was just wondering if there is a cleaner way without an additional database query.

There is a similar question here: [TYPO3 Extbase getArguments from other Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900978/typo3-extbase-getarguments-from-other-extension) but its from 2013, so maybe there is a way now.

Comment: Do you have the pluginB parameters in `$this->request`? An automatic transfer to the requested object ist not possible as it's "mapped" to a special controller and plugin.

Comment: PluginB does not have any parameters, I am only interested in the parameters from pluginA

Comment: So, same question with pluginA?

Comment: Using `$this->request` I only get the parameters of the current plugin, so if I am in pluginA I get the parameters I want, but not from pluginB. If I use  `$this->request` in pluginB I only get pluginB parameters which are none in my case.

Comment: Never tried it, but maybe it is possible to write an Middleware to map PluginA to PluginB parameters.